# how to handle error function in $http get

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, wordpress

I have a `$http.Get` function to get data from server it is working fine. I have 2 functions success & error function. if there is no data the error message should apply. but whenever I load the page it is showing `{{error.messageType}}{{error.message}}`.
can anyone help me.

html

```
<div align="center"> <span>{{error.messageType}}</span>
<br>
<span>{{error.message}}</span> </div>
```

**Script :**

```
$http.get(theFinalUrl).
    success(function (data) {
        $scope.outlets = data;
    });
    error(function (data) {
        $scope.error = data;
    });
```

Comment: Well you got a semicolon where you should have a `.`. I am guessing you did not look at your browser's console.

Comment: this a simple syntax error as @epascarello said

Comment: use [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

Comment: Mr. Epascarello can you edit this for me pls? still i did not get it done.

Comment: before **error** you should have a dot . and not ; ... like you did for **success**

Answer (score 0):

```js
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'api/url-api'
}).then(function (success){
  alert("success")
},function (error){
  alert("error")
});
```

**Reference Document:** [AngularJS $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)